# How to know the right path to the Joomla Configuration file on a external script

Tags: php, file, joomla

This is something that happens very often, the people moves the joomla configuration file from the root for security reasons but some external scripts can be affected.

Is possible to find the right path to the joomla configuration file in order to include this new path on a external script php script?

Answer (score 1):

save this in a file with name path.php, and then upload it to root of the host, then call it like: http://www.test.com/path.php

```
 <?php
 $path = getcwd();
 echo "Your Absoluthe Path is: ";
 echo $path;
 ?>
```

Comment: This is exactly the opposite of my question, I am asking how to determine the path to the joomla configuration file when this was moved from the path root.